# winrtrunner.exe не найден

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Пытаюсь прописать `quickcontrol2` в про файл.

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

> Выполняется поиск устройств WinRT.
>       winrtrunner.exe не найден.
>       Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quickcontrol2

Cреда Qt Creator.

Как это исправить? Если не сложно, распишите поподробней.

Comment: winrtrunner тут не при чем, а модуль называется `quickcontrols2`